# Alternative to `LoadPackagedLibrary` when having many functions to import

Tags: c++, dll, uwp

I know how to use `LoadPackagedLibrary` to load external module (a DLL) to the UWP application. The problem is that I have many functions with different signatures. Is there an easier way to import functions to the application, just like using header files in C++?

Comment: Do you need to delay-load? Do you have a header and `.lib` file that match the `.dll`?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I do not need delay-load and I do have header and the `.lib` accompanying the DLL.

Comment: You should be able to just link with the `.lib`... are you seeing errors from the linker?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `.lib` and header files, it's relatively easy to create C++/WinRT wrapper component which can expose all the features (functions) from the library. Let's assume that you have `test.lib` library and simple header file `test.h` like:

```
#pragma once

int add(int a, int b);
```

You should do the following:

1. Install [C++/WinRT VS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264);
2. Create "*Windows Runtime Component (C++/WinRT)*" project. Note that this project type comes from the extension from the first step. You **should not** use "*Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)*" project type which is in VS by default. Name the project `TestWrapper`;
3. Open project properties windows (right-click the project in Solution Explorer -> "Properties"), navigate to C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories, and add path of the directory which contains header files (`test.h`);
4. In the same properties window navigate to Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies, and add `test.lib` file path;
5. Add new MIDL file to the project (right-click -> Add... -> New item... -> C++ -> Code -> Midl file (.idl), and name file `Test.idl`. Add the following content:

```
namespace TestWrapper
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass Test
    {
        Test();
        static Int32 Add(Int32 a, Int32 b);
    }
}
```

6. Add new `Test.h` header file, with the following content:

```
#pragma once

#include "Test.g.h"

namespace winrt::TestWrapper::implementation
{
    struct Test: TestT<Test>
    {
        Test() = default;

        static int32_t Add(int32_t a, int32_t b);
    };
}

namespace winrt::TestWrapper::factory_implementation
{
    struct Test : TestT<Test, implementation::Test>
    {
    };
}
```

7. Add new `Test.cpp` file with the following content:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Test.h"
// if the original test.lib is C library you need to include 
// the header file in the following way:
extern "C" {
    #include "test.h"
}

namespace winrt::TestWrapper::implementation
{
    int32_t Test::Add(int32_t a, int32_t b)
    {
        // We are calling the original library method to get the result:
        return add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Finally you can reference the resulting component from any UWP app, written in any language (i.e. JavaScript). Here's how you can call the method from C#:

```
using TestWrapper;

class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var sum = Test.Add(2, 3);
    }
}
```

Here I implemented `Test.Add` as a static method, but it can be implemented as instance method also...

I hope it helped.